# warp windows desktop

Tags: windows, desktop, screenshot, distortion

I have read some threads and I know it is easy to warp a video. Now I want to warp windows desktop.The steps are:
1. Capture the desktop screen
2. Use desktop screen as a texture to a bezier surface mesh
The problem is the desktop screen captured isn't normal after first time when the desktop screen is distorted, so there is a endless loop. anyone can give me some suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't understand what you're talking about. Why isn't the desktop screen *"normal"* when it is captured the first time? My screen captures certainly look normal... Can you show the code that you've tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

You start with your original desktop capture, D. You distort it creating D1. Now if I understand your question, you are saying something like, "D1 is not the original image, so I can't use it as a texture for my next frame".

So, don't use D1. Use the original desktop capture as your source for every frame.